# AngularJS CORS Request from SSL Domain to non-SSL Domain fails with "Access Denied" before doing the call

Tags: angularjs, cors, internet-explorer-11, mixed-content

I am developing a LOB web application that runs on the local intranet using AngularJS (v1.4.8). One feature includes calling another intranet LOB web application using CORS/JSON. I was able to make the call and displaying the result in a near production environment, but when switching my application from http://servername/... to https://application-dns-entry.intranet.customer.com (SSL!) the feature dies with "Access is denied". Using F12 in IE11 (Fiddler isn't at my hands currently because of remote access restrictions) I realize a difference, my global error handler kicks in even before trying the request.

There is no localhost in play, all sites are local intranet zone, so other responses I found aren't really helpful. Is there a rule in IE's security understanding, that prevents calling a non-ssl-page when being inside an ssl-page? Or is there a feature inside AngularJS kicking in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, well, found Chrome in this remote desktop thingy, and his console is way more verbose:

[image: Screenshot from Chrome Console]

well, I'll discuss this with the other team, since intranet https isn't such an issue.